# Generating java proxy class in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a way in Eclipse to generate a proxy class (as in proxy pattern, not a remote call)? Something along the lines of this

```
public class FooBar{
    public int getBiz(){
        return 1234;
    } 
}
```

generates

```
public class FooBarProxy{
    protected FooBar foobar;
    public FooBarProxy(FooBar f) {...}
    public int getBiz(){
        return foobar.getBiz()
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create the proxy class yourself, and add the FooBar instance variable. Select the variable, right click-->source-->generate delegate methods

Comment: This is extremely useful when creating a decorator to change the behaviour of a specific method.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use java's built in dynamic proxy. It generates a proxy at runtime:

1. implement your proxy logic by implementing java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler
2. create a dynamic proxy; see http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html (example included)

Comment: It's interesting, but seems different usecase - mainly for interception/reflection magic.. For the plan old proxy pattern in Java, it's way messier than typing things out (also for debugging), IMHO. BTW, similar constructs look more acceptable in other languages (eg Forwardable in Ruby http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/forwardable/rdoc/Forwardable.html)